# Redirection with .htaccess inside a folder

Tags: .htaccess

I have a problem with a url a .htaccess.
I need that all url like : http://mywebsite.com/api/something go to my api/index.php cause I need to write a routing system from this place.
The .htacces must be inside the api/ folder.

What I'm trying to do here ,is a routing system who includes differents content inside the api/index.page depending on the url used.

For exemple if I go to http://mywebsite.com/api/activity I want to include a specific file without changing the url.

Do you think it's possible ? Have you an idea of the .htaccess content ?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Try to show some complete examples, hard to understand exactly what you want.

Comment: Yes, it is possible. No, we will not do your job for you. Look into mod_rewrite. If you get stuck feel free to come back here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've finally found the solution by myself so I post the solution, that may help another person later :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule (.*) index.php [PT,QSA]
</IfModule>
```